# Sorting a list by the car of each element in Racket

Tags: sorting, racket, cons

I want to sort a list by the car of each element, which is a cons cell. The car of each element is a number and the cdr part is a word. I can get a list of just sorted number. I tried to use this sorted number-list in order to sort my original list. but i don't really know what to do.

Here is my code:

```
(define (sort-by-car-number lst)               ;lst is a list with cons-pair 
 (let ((number-list (sort (map car lst) >)))   ;A list of sorted numbers 
       (cond
         ((null? lst) number-list)
         ((equal? (car number-list) (car (car lst)))
          (set! (car number-list)  (car lst))))
         (else (sort-by-car-number (cdr lst))))))
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
(sort-by-car-number (list '(4 . Blue) '(8 . Black) '(0 . Yellow) '(3 . Green)))    
; ==> ((8 . Black) (4 . Blue) (3 . Green) (0 . Yellow))
```

Comment: `(define (sort-by-car-number lst) (sort lst < #:key car))`.

Comment: if you'd define `(insert-by-car-number ...)` then you could for each element in `list1`, insert that element by car into a new list that would be thus built in sorted order, as `(set! new-list (insert-by-car-number element new-list))`. if you start with empty `new-list`, it will be ordered on every stage, by construction. when there are no more elements in `list1`, `new-list` is then its sorted version. this is known as insertion sort.

Comment: Thank you. The code suggestion of both of you were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Alexis comment works in `#lang racket` except OP wants descending order:

```scm
(define (sort-by-car-number lst) 
  (sort lst >= #:key car))

(sort-by-car-number '((4 . Blue) (8 . Black) (0 . Yellow) (3 . Green)))    
; ==> ((8 . Black) (4 . Blue) (3 . Green) (0 . Yellow))
```

As for a more standard Scheme without using `#:key` what will happen is the each **element** gets compared like `(>= '(4 . Blue) '(8 . Black))` so if you pass a comparison function that does this you have a general Scheme solution:

```scm
(define (sort-by-car-number lst) 
  (define (object-greater? a b)
    (>= (car a) (car b)))
  (sort lst object-greater?))
```